# How to do full join on one field and inner join on another from same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a query something like the following:

```
select      sum(t1.qty) t1Total, sum(t2.qty) t2Total, sum(t1.qty - t2.qty) difference
from        t1 full join 
            t2 on t1.date = t2.date and t1.chain = t2.chain
```

I want it to do an full join on the date, but an inner join on the chain.  In other words, one table has chains the other doesn't and I don't want the extra chains to be included in the total, but I do want to make sure that all days from a chain that's in both tables are accounted for.

What's the easiest way to do that?

Comment: Can you show a few rows of sample data from each table, and the results you want, making sure to include cases where either side is null? The word problem looks fun but I haven't had caffeine in at least a few hours, so it's not the best way to describe your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a case statement inside the sums;  set it to zero when the chain is null on the inner table. Eg:

```
sum(case when t2.chain is null then 0 else t1.qty end) as t1Total
```

Comment: How about in the where clause.  'where t2.chain is not null'.

Comment: @BrandonMoore but you don't want that; that would remove the full join for both columns.

Comment: I don't think so.  Together Chain and date make a record unique.  Obviously I don't want inner join because it could exclude dates.  But I 'want' to exclude chains that aren't in both.  Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results. Again, "could exclude" and "want to exclude" are vague descriptions. ACTUAL data and desired results will tell a much clearer story.

Comment: Actually they're not vague at all, but maybe you're just questioning whether I really meant what I said the way I said it... which I did :)  I actually ended up just doing a 'select distinct chain' statement on the one table and then hardcoding the results into a 'where chain in (...)' clause.  Problem with your answer is that the query is more complex than my example and I'd have to use case statements on every single field I want to include which is not ideal.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't your answer... should have said "problem with 'this' answer".